# multiline chart visualization with NeoDash

Tags: neo4j

I'm working with NeoDash to visualize a factor that is the result of pagesrank scores, the required output is normally a multiline chart of this factor for different countries over years(in X axis). I first tested my code for one country for 2019:

```
call gds.pageRank.stream("Morroco")
YIELD nodeId as names, score as score1
with gds.util.asNode(names).city AS city1, score1
ORDER BY score1 DESC, city1 ASC
call gds.pageRank.stream("other_countries")
YIELD nodeId as names, score AS score3
with gds.util.asNode(names).city AS city3, score3
ORDER BY score3 DESC, city3 ASC
with 2019 as x, score1/score3 as y
return x,y
```

but I got the error message below:

```
Variable `score1` not defined (line 9, column 17 (offset: 319))
"with 2019 as x, score1/score3 as y"
```

ps: the 'Morocco' graph is a filtered graph from the original one that is about this format : (:n1) -[:relation {year: , country: }]->(:n2)
I'm totally newbie to neo4j, I'll be so grateful if you help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WITH` acts as a projection in Neo4j, so whatever variables you specify in `WITH`, will be present further in the query. In your query:

```
call gds.pageRank.stream("Morroco")
YIELD nodeId as names, score as score1
with gds.util.asNode(names).city AS city1, score1
ORDER BY score1 DESC, city1 ASC
call gds.pageRank.stream("other_countries")
YIELD nodeId as names, score AS score3
with gds.util.asNode(names).city AS city3, score3 <-- You missed score1 here
ORDER BY score3 DESC, city3 ASC
with 2019 as x, score1/score3 as y
return x,y
```

Try this:

```
call gds.pageRank.stream("Morroco")
YIELD nodeId as names, score as score1
with gds.util.asNode(names).city AS city1, score1
ORDER BY score1 DESC, city1 ASC
call gds.pageRank.stream("other_countries")
YIELD nodeId as names, score AS score3
with gds.util.asNode(names).city AS city3, score3, score1
ORDER BY score3 DESC, city3 ASC
with 2019 as x, score1/score3 as y
return x,y
```